# Dynamically create a HTML form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how can I go about creating a form with javascript?

I have NO idea on how to proceed, I have been googling my face off but there is nothing definitive that can show me how to dynamically create forms with it.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Basically, exactly as you create other elements with JavaScript, using `createElement` or jQuery. Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Yes I can use jQuery, not too  familliar with it though.

Comment: I think you need to see some youtube tutorial first about javascript... 

Check out the net ninja or google chrome developers, there you have plenty info

Answer you question : 

var f = document.createElement("form");
document.body.appendchild.(f)

regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think posting a complete solution would be too much, but check out jQuery for this.
I give you a hint, jQuery's [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) could be very useful for you :)

Answer (score 42):

You could try something like this:

The HTML part:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>

 <body>
</html>
```

The javascript:

```
<script>
//create a form
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

//create input element
var i = document.createElement("input");
i.type = "text";
i.name = "user_name";
i.id = "user_name1";

//create a checkbox
var c = document.createElement("input");
c.type = "checkbox";
c.id = "checkbox1";
c.name = "check1";

//create a button
var s = document.createElement("input");
s.type = "submit";
s.value = "Submit";

// add all elements to the form
f.appendChild(i);
f.appendChild(c);
f.appendChild(s);

// add the form inside the body
$("body").append(f);   //using jQuery or
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f); //pure javascript

</script>
```

This way you can create as many elements as you want dynamically.

Comment: In case if the DOM is not loaded at the time of script execution, you may get an error -  In my case I got "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined". So better to enclose the javascript code inside window-onload block. 
E.g., 
<script>
window.onload = function(){
// javascript code here
}
</script>

Comment: @raj — If you have a question then [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Don't edit your question into someone else's answer!

Answer (score 3):

My idea is that you can use the [dform](https://github.com/daffl/jquery.dform) jquery plugin from github to create  forms directly by giving input as json data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create any amount of html including forms by running JavaScript,

Perhaps:

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <h1>My Form</h1>
    <div id="formcontent">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Our JavaScript might look like:

```js
var el = document.createElement("input");
el.type = "text";
el.name = "myformvar";

var cont = document.getElementById("formcontent")
cont.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: This is riddled with errors...your variable names don't match and you capitalized CreateElement and GetElementById

Answer (score 0):

use [document.write](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/basic/document-write.html) or if you want more flexibility use [jquery](http://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the standard DOM API (`document.createElement()`, [see these docs for an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536389(VS.85).aspx)) to create all the elements of the form.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to get the [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/) library and use its [`template`](https://underscorejs.org/#template) function to create your forms.  (If underscore is too large for you, the template function can stand on its own too).

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS...

```
 myWin = open("", "displayWindow", "width=800,height=500,status=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes");

                myWin.document.open();
                myWin.document.write("<html><head><title>V E N U S  </title>");
                myWin.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.hdr{.......}</style>");
                     myWin.document.write("</head><body onload='window.print()'>");
                          myWin.document.write("<div class='hdr'>");

                              myWin.document.write("what ever you want");
                              .
                              .


                         myWin.document.write("</div>");               
                     myWin.document.write("</body></html>");
                myWin.document.close();
```

that's will create a form with DIV inside it...