# line breaks/ styling text from javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, text, styling

So first of all, this might be a little long.
I'm trying to make a RPG text game, using javascript.

in my HTML, all i have is the html, head, css, body, a div and script tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="story_css.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<script src="story_js.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So this is going to purely be the container for the information from my game.

Then i have my javascript:

```
var ATTACK = 0;
var STRENGTH = 0;
var DEFENSE = 0;
var RANGED = 0;
var MAGIC = 0;
var AGILITY= 0;
var HEALTH = 0;
var CLASS = prompt("Choose a class (class only effects starting stats, but all classes can learn the same abilities at the same rate):Warrior, Mage, Theif, Archer.").toUpperCase();
switch (CLASS){
    case "WARRIOR":
        ATTACK = 16;
        STRENGTH = 18;
        DEFENSE = 17;
        RANGED = 2;
        MAGIC = 2;
        AGILITY = 5;
        HEALTH = 200;
        break;

    case "ARCHER":
        ATTACK = 6;
        STRENGTH = 5;
        DEFENSE = 11;
        RANGED = 20;
        MAGIC = 3;
        AGILITY = 15;
        HEALTH = 175;
    break;
}

document.write("These are the levels for each of your characters skills. You may write these down and keep track of them, but the game will automatically record your progress for you. However, you will not be able to see your levels until you type a command that asks for them, or if you require a certain level to complete a task.")
var  NAME = prompt("Enter your name:");

confirm("You are about to embark on an epic quest... so, " + NAME + " are you ready to begin?");

document.write("It is the year 3355, according to the Delil calendar, and you awake from your night's sleep. Today is a special day. It is your 18th birthday! In your small village of Shadowhollow, you are one of the 23 people who live there. But as of today, you are one of the villages men.");
```

My problem is, that when the javascript is doing the document.write part, it just puts it as one giant piece of texts, eve if they came from different prompts. Could someone help me and tell my how to style it?

Comment: You should switch to the usage of [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) instead of `document.write()`.

Comment: [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.createElement) is as well reccomended

Comment: Stop using `document.write()`! You won't be happy with it, as it doesn't do what you think it does. Most importantly it overwrites the content of your whole page deleting everything, including the script you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.write("<h2>A sample heading</h2>\
<p>These are the levels for each of your characters skills.\
You may write these down and keep track of them, but the game will automatically record your progress for you.\
However, you will not be able to see your levels until you type a command that asks for them, \
or if you require a certain level to complete a task.</p>");
var  NAME = prompt("Enter your name:");

confirm("You are about to embark on an epic quest... so, " + NAME + " are you ready to begin?");

document.write("<h2>A sample heading</h2>\
<p>It is the year 3355, according to the Delil calendar, and you awake from your night's sleep. \
Today is a special day. It is your 18th birthday! In your small village of Shadowhollow, you are one of the 23 people who live there. \
But as of today, you are one of the villages men.</p>");
```

You can use `backslash` to split a string over different lines in javascript.

You can use different text markup tags like `<p>` for paragraph `<h1>` for heading1 etc to style the text, which in turn is a part of `HTML`. For more stlyling you can take a look at `css`.

If you want line breaks in javascript use `\n` or `\t` for tabs. This is just for output formatting.

If you want line breaks in the `HTML` result, use `<br>`

> Also the `document.write` method is deprecated and not recommended, if
>   you are serious about your programming. You have to resort to better
>   DOM manipulation methods like `document.createElement` `appendChild`
>   etc to create a document dynamically.

[Dynamically create a HTML form with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297143/dynamically-create-a-html-form-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't structure your text with HTML?:

```
document.write('<p>...</p>');
...
document.write('<p>...</p>');
```